# Recursive backtracking to generate mazes

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursive-backtracking

I'm trying to write a maze generator using the recursive backtracking algorithm. I've taken the example code from [this article](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2010/12/27/maze-generation-recursive-backtracking) and more or less translated it to javascript. But it doesn't seem to work as all the rows are identical in the generated grid.

I don't know anything about this kind of thing and I'm stuck here. Anybody can see what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit**: [jsfiddle](http://jsbin.com/oxunALe/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
// initialize the grid
var grid = []
  , cells = []
  // duplicate to avoid overriding
  , w = width
  , h = height
while (w--) cells.push(0)
while (h--) grid.push(cells)

var N = 1
  , S = 2
  , E = 4
  , W = 8
  , dirs = ['N', 'E', 'S', 'W']
  , dirsValue = { N: N, E: E, S: S, W: W }
  , DX = { E: 1, W: -1, N: 0, S: 0 }
  , DY = { E: 0, W: 0, N: -1, S: 1 }
  , OPPOSITE = { E: W, W: E, N: S, S: N }

function carve_passages_from(cx, cy, grid) {
  var directions = shuffle(dirs)

  directions.forEach(function(direction) {
    var nx = cx + DX[direction]
      , ny = cy + DY[direction]

    if (ny >= 0 && ny <= (grid.length - 1) && nx >= 0
      && nx <= (grid.length - 1) && grid[ny][nx] === 0) {
      grid[cy][cx] += dirsValue[direction]
      grid[ny][nx] += OPPOSITE[direction]
      carve_passages_from(nx, ny, grid)
    }
  })
}

carve_passages_from(0, 0, grid)

return grid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the statement:

```js
while (h--) grid.push(cells)
```

You are using the same array for each row of the `grid`.

To solve it, you should create a new array for each row:

```js
while (h--) grid.push(new Array(w))
```

And finally, replace all `undefined` in the grid with `0`, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I filled in the problematic code with the two suggestions by @musically_ut .  Here's the result:

```
function shuffle(o){
      for (var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
      return o;
  };

var width = 10
  , height = 10

// initialize the grid
    var grid = []
      , cells = []
      // duplicate to avoid overriding
      , w = width
      , h = height
    while (h--) grid.push(new Array(w))
    while (w--) cells.push(0)
    for(var r = 0; r < height; r++){
      for(var c = 0; c < width; c++){
        grid[r][c] = 0;
      }
    }
    
    var N = 1
      , S = 2
      , E = 4
      , W = 8
      , dirs = ['N', 'E', 'S', 'W']
      , dirsValue = { N: N, E: E, S: S, W: W }
      , DX = { E: 1, W: -1, N: 0, S: 0 }
      , DY = { E: 0, W: 0, N: -1, S: 1 }
      , OPPOSITE = { E: W, W: E, N: S, S: N }

    function carve_passages_from(cx, cy, grid) {
      var directions = shuffle(dirs)

      directions.forEach(function(direction) {
        var nx = cx + DX[direction]
          , ny = cy + DY[direction]

        if (ny >= 0 && ny <= (grid.length - 1) && nx >= 0
          && nx <= (grid.length - 1) && grid[ny][nx] === 0) {
          grid[cy][cx] += dirsValue[direction]
          grid[ny][nx] += OPPOSITE[direction]
          carve_passages_from(nx, ny, grid)
        }
      })
    }

    carve_passages_from(0, 0, grid)

    document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = grid
```